# How to mock and test ApolloClient graphql query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, apollo-client, react-testing-library

I'm trying to mock and test an API call done with ApolloClient in React using Jest and react-testing-library. But it looks like the call never happens.

The code is spread out over three files in the same /src directory:

/src/apolloClient.js holds a client instance:

```
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";

export const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://api.github.com/graphql",
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
    }
  });
```

query.js holds the graphql query and the function that makes the call:

```
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
import { client } from "../apolloClient";

export const userQuery = gql`
  query($login: String!) {
    user(login: $login) {
      name
      email
      ...
    }
  }
`;

export const getGitHubProfile = (userLogin, setUser) =>
  client
    .query({ query: userQuery, variables: { login: userLogin } })
    .then(response => setUser(response.data.user))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Landing.js holds the form that makes the call:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { getGitHubProfile } from "./query";
import CV from "./CV";

function Landing() {
  const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  const submitUserLogin = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    userLogin && getGitHubProfile(userLogin, setUser); // Called here on submit.
  };

  const gitHubUsernameForm = () => {
    return (
          ...
          <form
            data-testid="form"
            className="form field has-addons"
            onSubmit={submitUserLogin}
          >
            <div className="control has-icons-left">
              <input
                className="input"
                type="text"
                name="github-username"
                aria-label="github-username"
                placeholder="What's your GitHub username?"
                defaultValue="Bobby"
                onChange={e => setUserLogin(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="control">
              <button data-testid="button" className="button">
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
          ...
    );
  };

  return user ? <CV data-testid="CV" user={user} /> : gitHubUsernameForm();
}

export default Landing;
```

Basically, clicking submit in Landing.js triggers `submitUserLogin()`, which runs `getGitHubProfile()` in query.js to use `client` from apolloClient.js to ask GitHub for stuff.

If the call is made, `<CV data-testid="CV" user={user} />` is made to appear. It's not there now but I've also tried inserting `user ? <p data-testid="CV">Testing only</p> : null` in the layout in case `data-testid` doesn't work on components (I'm not familiar with testing yet).

This works well on the site itself when I run `npm start`.

However, I can't figure out how to test if the API call is made. After reading the docs on Apollo and react-testing-library and trying a lot of things, this is what I think is closest to a workable solution right now:

```
import Landing from "../Landing";
import { MockedProvider } from "@apollo/react-testing";
import { userQuery } from "../query";

const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: userQuery,
      variables: {
        login: "Bobby"
      }
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        user: { location: "South Woobeewoo" }
      }
    }
  }
];

it("Calls API", async () => {
  const { getByLabelText, getByText, getByTestId } = render(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
      <Landing />
    </MockedProvider>
  );
  const input = getByLabelText("github-username");
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "Bobby" } });
  console.log(input.value); // Shows input is successful.

  fireEvent.click(getByText("Submit"));

  const response = await waitForElement(() => getByTestId("CV")); // Always fails here.
  expect(response).toBeTruthy();
});
```

The test always fails with "Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="CV"]".

I know `fireEvent.click()` works because I've also tried having this click event set a `pressed` state (now removed) to trigger the appearance of test elements labelled with `data-testid="CV"`.

I've tried the testing pattern in the official Apollo docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/), firing submit on the form itself like [here](https://kula.blog/posts/test_on_submit_in_react_testing_library/), this [one](https://dev.to/potouridisio/test-the-what-and-not-the-how-5h40) too. Also read through the testing docs [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events) on firing events.

I think I'm just really not doing mocking correctly somehow. What am I doing wrong?